# Modify subroutine parameter (Perl)

Tags: perl, parameters, subroutine

I want to write a Perl subroutine `first` which takes a list as an input, returns the first element in the list and removes the first element from the list.

Like this:

```
@list = (1,2,3);
print first(@list); // 1
print @list; // 23
```

This is not quite working:

```
sub first(@) {
    return shift @_;
}
```

What I get is:

```
print first(@list); // 1
print @list; // 123
```

The stack variable @_ changes the way I expect it to (first it is `(1, 2, 3)` then it is `(2, 3)`), but the list I give as an input (`@list`) is not changed. I thought the stack variable saves a reference to the variable it refers to.

When I change a list element in the subroutine it also changes something in `@list` but not the one I wanted to, but that one + 1. So if I in the subroutine I were to write:

```
@_[0] = "X";
```

and after executing the subroutine print `@list`, I would get `2X6`.

Comment: Why not use `shift` to achieve this?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the subroutine

Comment: But why would you like to write the subroutine? When you could simply use `shift`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a slash in front of the `@` prototype to get an array reference, and then modify the reference. If you just use `@` you will get a copy of the array `@list` in the subroutine (and the array in the parent would therefore not be modified). From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes:

> Unbackslashed prototype characters have special meanings. Any
>   unbackslashed @ or % eats all remaining arguments, and forces list
>   context.

So you could write:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub first (\@) {
    my $a = shift;
    return shift @$a;
}

my @list = (1,2,3);
print first(@list) . "\n"; 
print "@list" . "\n";
```

Output:

```
1
2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have lists there, you have arrays. Arrays and lists are different in Perl (as this [great blog post](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl) explains). If you have an array called `@list` then you're just guaranteed to confuse yourself (and whoever maintains your code in the future).